# Can a class instance in a class attribute access its outer class? ~ Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm wondering how you can access outer classes from the scope of class instances in an attribute of the outer class. I have heard of the `super()` function, but it only works for inheritance.

To make things clear, I have given an example:

```
class Outside:
    def __init__(self, spam, ham):
        self.eggs = spam * ham
        self.inside_class = Inside()

class Inside:
    def double_eggs(self):
        # TODO: return the attribute eggs mulitplied by 2
```

Comment: How are you planning to call `double_eggs()`? If you are calling it from the `Outside` class, you could just pass `eggs` as an argument.

Comment: Or you could make Inside take a `parent` argument on initialisation, and pass in `self`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for your comment, I'm a beginner coder in Python, can you please explain what it means?

Comment: @HUAN5235 Whose attribute eggs?

Comment: @Goyo `Outside`'s

Comment: @HUAN5235  `Outside` does not have an attribute `eggs` (`Outside.eggs` will raise `AttributeError`). Instances of `Outside` have, but it is not clear what instance you want, there isn't any in your code.

Comment: @Goyo Whoops! I meant an *instance* of `Outside`. Sorry

Comment: @HUAN5235 What instance?

Comment: @Goyo When I create an *instance* of `Outside`, I want `Inside` to be able to access `Outside`'s `eggs` instance attribute.

Comment: @HUAN5235 Again, there is no "`Outside`'s `eggs`" class attribute. It is an instance attribute.

Comment: @HUAN5235 Just pass the instance as an argument `def double_eggs(self, outside)`? Then you can access any attribute of `outside` in the body of `double_eggs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Inside needs a reference to Outside, you should pass it.

```
class Inside:
    def __init__(self, outside):
        self.outside = outside
    def double_eggs(self):
        return self.outside.eggs * 2

class Outside:
    def __init__(self, spam, ham):
        self.eggs = spam * ham
        self.inside_class = Inside(self)
```

Comment: Does the variable `self` in the class `Outside` refer to the class `Outside`, or it refers to an *instance* of `Outside`?

Comment: @Huan5235 unless a method is a classmethod or a staticmethod, the first argument is always the *instance* which invoked the method

Answer (score 1):

References are one-way, an object does not know who is refering to it. So it is not possible the way you set up your classes.

Although, what you seem to want is for `Inside` to extend the functionalities of `Outside`. You do this with inheritance.

```
class Outside:
    def __init__(self, spam, ham):
        self.eggs = spam * ham

class Inside(Outside):
    def double_eggs(self):
        return self.eggs * 2

obj = Inside(1, 2)
print(obj.double_eggs()) # 4
```

Comment: Is there a way to *not* use inheritance? If it's hopeless, then I'll change my code.

Comment: @HUAN5235 It definitely cannot be done the way you want. There would be other ways than inheritance. But inheritance serves exactly that purpose so there is no reason not to use it.